# C# Looking for Non-existent Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I am having a strange issue... I am getting this error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.
>
> Error Code: 0x80070003 (Cannot Read Configuration file)
>
> Config File:
>   \?\E:\TFSLocal\Trunk\loggerTrunk\CommonLogViewer\web.config
>
> Requested
>   URL:  http://localhost:80/CommonLogViewer/Search/GetAppModules
>
> Physical
>   Path: E:\TFSLocal\Trunk\loggerTrunk\CommonLogViewer\GetAppModules

It has to do with the path that the app is trying to find the web.config at. I have never had any files at the Physical path that is listed in the error, so I am not sure why it would be trying to look there. The correct path should be:

> E:\TFSLocal\MVC Logger\20150723\CommonLogViewer\Search\GetAppModules

I have done searches in the code for a match to that path and also in the IIS and have come up with nothing. Incidentally, the Physical path listed in the IIS is:

> E:\TFSLocal\MVC Logger\20150723\CommonLogViewer

Which is the correct path the code files.

Can someone give me a push in the right direction as to how to fix this error?

I have been looking at this for about a day now and haven't come up with a solution as to why it would be looking in a non-existent folder for the `web.config.`

Comment: Did you check that site does not have and "Virtual directories" (that likely the answer since root of the site does not match "Search" path).

Comment: There are no Virtual Directories for this site

Comment: Is this E drive a mapped drive?

Comment: The E drive is the local disk drive

Comment: Personally, I am starting to believe that this is an issue with either Visual Studio 2012 or with TFS 2013 holding on to an old Code path...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did not find a solution, but I found a work around. I noticed that every time I tried to access the search controller, it gave the error, but no where else. So I created a new controller and used that instead of the search controller and everything seems to be going well...

I still don’t have a clue why it tries to search for that web.config in a non-existent file path … but it’s working currently and that is most important...

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue and eventually solved it by opening my application host config file and deleting the existing settings.

`C:\Users\<USER>\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`

I deleted the entire `<site name="blah"... </site>` for the site I was having a problem with.